# In Orleans when to use IGrainFactory vs IClusterClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, orleans

This is a Orleans application in a co-hosted model (ASP.NET - Web API and Orleans).
I am able to inject IGrainFactory or IClusterClient into a webapi controller.
Both seem to get the work fine.

I want to understand, when to use IGrainFactory and when to use IClusterClient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IClusterClient is meant to be used from the client which is accessing the silo cluster. In your case, it is the webapi controller. IGrainFactory is used in a service class within a silo to get an instance of a Grain.

Maybe the article below can shed some light.
https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/988

Comment: You can use either. Both IClusterClient and IGrainFactory are available to you whether you're in a silo or an external client (eg web frontend). Which one you choose is up to you, but typically I would suggest IGrainFactory. IClusterClient implements IGrainFactory and adds a few other methods. Most of those methods are specific to an external client (connect, abort), but there's also GetStreamProvider for accessing streams.